# ROS Groovy and libavcodec-extra-53 compatibility

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I want to install libavcodec-extra-53 instead of libavcodec53 (AFAIK the latter should include everything from the former plus some other codecs). However, when I try to do so it forces me to remove all my ROS installation. Is there any way to make ROS compatible with libavcodec-extra-53?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61376/ros-groovy-and-libavcodec-extra-53-compatibility/) by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thank you, at least now I know that it is possible :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There must be, because I have ROS groovy + libavcodec-extra-53 installed right now. Unfortunately, I don't know any surefire command that will resolve any conflicts. I usually hunt down the conflicts using aptitude and do a little uninstall-reinstall dance until everything's installed.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1